# jQuery Ajax - still reloading the page - Laravel pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a problem with my Laravel pagination and Ajax. My Ajax still reloading the page, and I don't know why and how to fix it? I want to avoid reloading the page.

**LATER EDIT :**
  With this Ajax I got an error : `Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive` . I fixed that with `document.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.mousewheel.bind(this), { passive: false });`
, but now my page is reloading.

*Here is my view:*

```
<div id="initiated" class="profile-edit tab-pane fade" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0;">


    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center u-nav-v5-3 u-nav-primary  " role="tablist" data-target="nav-5-3-primary-hor-center" data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down" data-btn-classes="btn btn-md btn-block u-btn-outline-primary" style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;">
  <li class="nav-item active">
     <a a data-toggle="tab" href="#grid" style="font-size: 12px"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> Grid</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a a data-toggle="tab" href="#list" style="font-size: 12px"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> List</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="grid" class="tab-pane fade in active">

            <?php $count_user = 0;

         ?>
      @foreach($initiated as $record)


                    @if($count_user == 0)
                        <div class="row margin-bottom-20 ">
                    @endif
                    <?php $count_user++; ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 sm-margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="profile-blog">
                            <img style="border-radius: 0% !important" class="rounded-x" src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->profile_picture : '' }}" alt="">
                            <div class="name-location" style="top: 30px;position: relative">
                                @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-user"></i>

                                    @elseif($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>

                                    @endif

                                 <a id="my-link" style="color: #555;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}">{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}</a></h3>

                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix "></div>

                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i>Location : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->country : '' }} <span class="{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->flag : '' }}"></span><br>
                            <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i style="padding: 5px" class="icon-notebook fa-"></i>Industry : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->industry->industry : '' }}<br>
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(isset($record->user->organization_type->organization_type))
                                <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg" style="padding: 5px;font-size: 13px"></i>Organization : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->organization_type->organization_type : '' }}@endif
                            @endif
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(!empty($record->user->career_path[0]))
                                <strong style="font-size: 13px"><i class="icon-speedometer" style="padding: 5px"></i>Function : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->career_path[0]->functions->function : '' }}@endif
                            @endif


                            <hr>
                            <ul class="list-inline share-list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="/cancel-invitation/{{$record->id}}"><i class="fa fa-times"> </i>Cancel</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if($count_user == 2)
                        </div>
                        <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>

                    @endif
                    @endforeach

    </div>
    <div id="list" class="tab-pane fade">
        <?php $count_user = 0;

         ?>


                @foreach($initiated_tab_2 as $record)

                    @if($count_user == 0)
                        <div class="row">
                    @endif
                    <?php $count_user++; ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 sm-margin-bottom-20" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
                        <div class="profile-blog" style="padding: 5px">
                            <img style="margin-right: 10px" src="{{ asset('thumbnail') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->profile_picture : '' }}" alt="">
                            <div class="name-location">

                                <h3>    @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-user"></i>

                                    @elseif($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;position: relative;" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>


                                    @endif <a id="my-link" style="color: #555;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}">{{ $record->user ? $record->user->username : '' }}</a></h3>

                                <ul class="list-inline share-list d-flex pull-right" style="bottom: 25px;position: relative;margin-bottom: -20px;left: -25px">
                                <li style="left: 25px;position: relative">
                                    <a href="/cancel-invitation/{{$record->id}}"><i class="icon-custom-me rounded fa fa-times"> </i></a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>

                            </div>


                            <div style="display: flex;right: 2px;position: relative;bottom: 12px;margin-bottom: -10px">
                                <div style="padding-right: 15px">
                        <strong><i class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i> : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->country : '' }} <span class="{{ $record->user ? $record->user->country->flag : '' }}"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding-right: 10px">

                         <strong><i class="icon-screen-tablet fa-"></i> : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->industry->industry : '' }}
                                </div>
                            <div style="padding-right: 10px">
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'organizations' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(isset($record->user->organization_type->organization_type))
                                <strong><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->organization_type->organization_type : '' }}
                                @endif
                            @endif
                            </div>
                            <div style="padding-right: 10px">
                            @if($record->user->role[0]->slug == 'individuals' ? $record->user->role[0]->slug : '')
                            @if(!empty($record->user->career_path[0]))

                            <strong><i class="icon-frame fa-"></i>  : </strong>{{ $record->user ? $record->user->career_path[0]->functions->function : '' }}
                            @endif
                            @endif
                            </div>
                            </div>
                                                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @if($count_user == 2)
                        </div>
                        <?php  $count_user = 0; ?>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach


    </div>
  </div>







    </dl>
    {!! $initiated->render() !!}

</div>
```

*Here is my script:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxPaging() {
    $('.pagination a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#initiated').load(url + ' div#initiated', null, ajaxPaging); // re-run on complete
    });
}
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.mousewheel.bind(this), { passive: false });

ajaxPaging();
</script>
```

*Here is my controller:*

```
$initiated =  \App\Invitation::with('user')
    ->where('inviter_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: Maybe this? `[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>`

Comment: I added this : `document.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.mousewheel.bind(this), { passive: false });
` . Now, I don't have any error, but my ajax didn't working, still refreshing the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : 
 - here #master-data is the id of section where you want to show your data . Replace it with yours . Or modify code as per your need.

```
  $("body").on('click', '.pagination a',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
        var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        getData(page);
    });

/* Ajax function to make ajax request. */

 function getData(page=1){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{url("your url")}}',
            data:'page='+page, 
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function( response) {

                if(response.status==102){
                    $('#master-data').html(response.html);
                } else {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey. I added this code. I've changed to $('#my-list').html(response.html); and added a div with `id="my-list"` above the foreach. Now, when I press on other pages, nothing happens.

Comment: What should I write here? `url: '{{url("your url")}}',` ? The url of the page?

Comment: also u can track ur ajax request in console